# Matching Type Parameters on Traits

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a trait like:

```
trait MyTrait[T, U <: SomeParentClass] {
  def get(data: T): Option[U]
}
```

and a concrete implementation like:

```
case class MyStringClass[U <: SomeParentClass](f: String => Option[U])
  extends MyTrait[String, U] {
  override def get(data: String) = f(data)
}
```

To simplify things, let's also say we have the following types for `U <: SomeParentClass`:

- `TypeA`
- `TypeB`
- `TypeC`

and some functions:

- `def str2TypeA(s: String): Option[TypeA] = ...`
- `def str2TypeB(s: String): Option[TypeB] = ...`
- `def str2TypeC(s: String): Option[TypeC] = ...`

Then let's say I have:

```
val mySeq = Seq(
  MyStringClass(str2TypeA),
  MyStringClass(str2TypeB),
  MyStringClass(str2TypeC)
)
```

What I want to do is filter `mySeq` based on the return type `U`. Something like:

```
mySeq.collect { case a: Function1[_, Option[TypeA]] => a}
```

I'm running into type erasure issues as expected. I'm curious what approaches might work well here to achieve my goal of filtering based on the type `U`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually use a [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) to handle cases where erasure gets in your way. They are essentially simple objects that contain all of the information available at compile-time, and they're easy to obtain either by requesting an implicit parameter, or just writing `typeTag[T]`. For example:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class MyStringClass[U <: SomeParentClass](f: String => Option[U])(implicit val utt: TypeTag[U])
  extends MyTrait[String, U] {
  override def get(data: String) = f(data)
}

mySeq.collect {
  case a: MyStringClass[Option[TypeA]] if (a.utt == typeTag[Option[Type[A]]) => a
}
```